# Play MP4 with Psychopy

Tags: python, mp4, psychopy

I'm having problems finding a solution to play a mp4 file with psychopy.
Should I put the file in a special folder? How can I find this folder? And is there a special function to open then the file when running the code?

I tried making a class, but I have problems when defining the path.
Please taking in consideration that I just started programming.
[Probe-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22gYC.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post your code with the "code sample" formatting instead of a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

```py
import playsound
playsound.playsound('sample.mp3')
```

Process to play this song: first create a file play.mp3 and copy the path of file and paste that code on the place of sample.mp3 in your code editor.